# Struts2 url not hitting correct action

Tags: ajax, struts2

I have written an ajax call for calling an struts2 action, its by default going to execute method but not for any method defined in struts.xml. Please tell me how to form the url in the javascript to call the correct action with the method defined in struts.xml

code:

```
 function showCustomer(str) {
    emailRequest = createRequest();
    if (emailRequest == null){
        alert("Unable to create request");
        }else{
        var emailValue = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var email = escape(emailValue); 
        alert(email)
        var url= "recoverPassword!recoverPassword?email="+email;
        alert(url)
        emailRequest.onreadystatechange = showemailStatus;
        emailRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        emailRequest.send(null);
    }
}

function showemailStatus() {
    if (emailRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (emailRequest.status == 200) {
            if (emailRequest.responseText.match("EamilIdExists")) {
                document.getElementById("show").style.display='block';
            } else {
                    document.getElementById("email").focus();
                    alert("Email id doesnot exist");
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

struts.xml:

```
 <action name="recoverPassword" class="com.astro.action.CheckEmailAction" method="recoverPassword">
            <result type="stream" name="success">
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            </result>
            <result type="stream" name="input">
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Comment: By the way you have **NEVER accepted ANY answer**. When an answer helps you, click on the white `V` mark on the top left corner of the answer, turning it to green. Both you and the answerer will get reputation points, and it will immediately tell future visitors that the answer was right. You should do on your old answers too, when they worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change action name: the same Action Class can be declared multiple times with multiple names, with (and without) different methods. And when you change the name, you don't have to use the bang `!` character anymore (*Dynamic Method Invocation*, that you must explicitly activate on struts.xml, can bring security issues, so it would be better to avoid it)

   Then you could have

   ```
   <action class = "com.astro.action.CheckEmailAction" 
            name = "recoverPasswordAction" 
          method = "recoverPassword">
   ...
   ```

   and

   ```
   <action class = "com.astro.action.CheckEmailAction" 
            name = "doSomethingElseAction" 
          method = "doSomethingElse">
   ...
   ```

   (always remembering that an Action shouldn't perform too much different logical "actions")
2. Then, to inject it in javascript, use `<s:url>` (with namespace, IF needed) and `<s:param>` (if needed). In your case, your param is read at runtime from the page so you need to append it with javascript to the generated url:

   ```
   var url = "<s:url action="recoverPasswordAction" />?email="+email;
   ```

Comment: You need 15 reputation points to VOTE, but you already have enough reputation to ACCEPT, by marking the white V in top left corner of the answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Can anyone please help in fixing the url  so that it hits the correct action with correct method name in the action class. If i am not putting any method name in the url, then its hitting execute method in struts2. But i dont want it to hit the execute method

Comment: Once i got it with this type of situation one year back but i forgot it now and struggling how to hit the correct method.

Comment: Any one can please help me with this issue ?

Comment: Got the solution, thanks to Andrea. Only thing is that i have just chnaged one line of code in javascript. That is :var url= "recoverPasswordAction!recoverPassword.do?email="+email; I forgot .do previously